# Where is 'cost' in the Google Ads API

Tags: google-ads-api

I cannot locate where 'cost' exists within the Google Ads API (not the adwords API).

Can anyone help identify what it is called?

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v10/campaign?hl=en

Answer (score 4):

It's called [`metrics.cost_micros`](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v10/campaign?hl=en#metrics.cost_micros) and can be found in the "Metrics" column of the documentation page you linked to.